# How to call Stored Procedure with Joins in Entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

.Net core 3.1

This is my [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvNs3.png)

I am not allowed to add any foreign keys or new relation into them. I made a stored procedure that joins other 3 tables to Ordering_Policy table.

```
create procedure spOrderingPolicy
as
    select op.Id, op.Tyre_Grade, op.Tyre_Group, tb.Tyre_Brand, ss.Status, tc.Cosmetic
    from [dbo].[Ordering_Policy] as op

    left join [dbo].[Tyre_Brand] as tb
    on op.Tyre_Brand_Id = tb.Id
    left join [dbo].[Shearography_Status] as ss
    on op.Shearography_Id = ss.Id
    left join [dbo].[Tyre_Cosmetic] as tc
    on op.Cosmetic_Id = tc.Id
go
```

The result [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKeaB.png) is as expected:

So I tried to call the procedure:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderingPolicy> GetOrder()
{
    using (Ordering_PolicyContext context = new Ordering_PolicyContext())
    {
        var order = context.OrderingPolicies.FromSqlRaw<OrderingPolicy>("spOrderingPolicy").ToList();
        return order;
    }
}
```

But it ignores anything not in the Ordering_Policy: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKMWJ.png)

How do I call the procedure and displays all the data like in the query?

Edit: This is the class for OrderingPolicy

```
namespace Ordering_Policy.Models
{
    public partial class OrderingPolicy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TyreGrade { get; set; }
        public int? TyreGroup { get; set; }
        public int? ShearographyId { get; set; }
        public string CasingLife { get; set; }
        public string Variance { get; set; }
        public string ColorCode { get; set; }
        public string Injury { get; set; }
        public int? MaxCrownPatch { get; set; }
        public int? MaxShoulder { get; set; }
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        public int? CosmeticId { get; set; }
        public int? TyreBrandId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in your list "order" ? Do you have tha data you need in this variable ?

Comment: Please don't use images where text is possible. Also, we can't see the `OrderingPolicy` class.

Comment: Can you show you OrderingPolicie class pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally able to find the solution: Make new class and context solely to call the columns from the stored procedure

Class:

```
public partial class Tyre_Detail
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string Tyre_Grade { get; set; }
    public int? Tyre_Group { get; set; }
    public string Tyre_Brand { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Cosmetic { get; set; }
}
```

The data must have the same name exactly like the columns from the stored procedure. There are no keys in this class so the data type, in this case is `int` needs to have question mark.

Then create the context file for the class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tyre_Detail>(entity =>
{
     entity.HasNoKey();

     entity.Property(e => e.Id);
     entity.Property(e => e.Tyre_Grade);
     entity.Property(e => e.Tyre_Group);
     entity.Property(e => e.Tyre_Brand);
     entity.Property(e => e.Status);
     entity.Property(e => e.Cosmetic);
     });
```

Since this is keyless entities, .HasNoKey() is essential.

Comment: Are you sure that we need to mark the int properties as nullable? This does only mean they are mandatory, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations) that matches the resultset returned by your stored procedure, and call `OrderingPolicyEx.FromSqlRaw` on that DbSet and not `OrderingPolicy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **INNER Join** rather than left Join:

This is My demo,with your entity class(a little simplified):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spOrderingPolicy]  
as

select op.Id, op.TyreGrade, 
op.TyreGroup,op.CosmeticId,op.ShearographyId,op.TyreBrandId, tb.Brand, ss.status, 
tc.cosmetic
from dbo.OrderingPolicy as op

INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tyre_Brand] as tb
on op.TyreBrandId = tb.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Shearography_Status] as ss
on op.ShearographyId = ss.Id
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tyre_Cosmetic] as tc
on op.CosmeticId = tc.Id
Go
```

Result:only matched rows will be showed

[image]